# Abbreviation of "collapse" in paste?

Tags: r, argument-matching, partial-matches

Using the command `paste` in R, I wanted to use both arguments `sep` and `collapse`, but you cannot abbreviate `collapse` to `coll` or even `collaps`.  Yet for other functions partial abbreviation works.

For example:

```
paste(letters, colla=", ")
# [1] "a , " "b , " "c , " "d , " "e , " "f , " "g , " "h , " "i , " "j , " "k , " "l , " "m , " "n , " "o , " "p , " "q , " "r , "
[19] "s , " "t , " "u , " "v , " "w , " "x , " "y , " "z , "
paste(letters, collapse=", ")
# [1] "a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z"
```

There are no other arguments to collapse that start with `coll`, which would interfere with the partial argument matching.

Why must I type out the entire argument name when calling `paste`, when I do not have to for other functions?

Comment: I would actually really not use this kind of abbreviation as it is harder to read and can have unforseen consequences as the expansion could lead to the wrong parameter matching.

Answer (score 23):

I believe it's the `...` in paste that causes that you have to use exact argument matching.  Specifically, the fact that `,collapse` comes *after* the `...` in the argument list.

Demonstration:

```
f1 <- function(x, collapse) cat("collapse",collapse)
f2 <- function(..., collapse) cat("collapse",collapse)
f3 <- function(collapse, ...) cat("collapse",collapse)

> f1(c="test",1)
collapse test
> f2(1,c="test")
Error in base::cat(...) : argument "collapse" is missing, with no default
> f2(1,collapse="test")
collapse test
> f3(c="test",1)
collapse test
```

Comment: This is my understanding as well.  There is a warning "somewhere" in the R documentation that any named argument following `...` cannot be shortened.

Comment: It's documented in [section 4.3.2 Argument matching](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Argument-matching) of [R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html).

Comment: So the hacker in me suggests `mypaste <-function(sep = " ", collapse = NULL,...) paste(sep,collapse,...)`   :-)

Answer (score 2):

A wrapper function might be helpful, much like `paste0`

```
p <- function(..., s=" ", clap=NULL) {   # or whichever abbreviation you prefer. I originally had `col`, but that was dumb. 
   paste(..., sep=s, collapse=clap)
}

p0 <- function(...,  clap=NULL) {
   paste(..., sep="", collapse=clap)
}
```

eg :

```
p(c("hello", "world"), c("abc", "123"), clap="$")
# [1] "hello abc$world 123"


p0(c("hello", "world"), c("abc", "123"), clap="$")
# [1] "helloabc$world123"
```

Comment: While this might be of use to the OP, I don't think it really answers the question of *why* the abbreviation doesn't work, which Ari's answer does...

Comment: @Carl, thanks for the cleanup.   Ananda: I think you're right about the exactness, still this may be helpful to the OP.  I think Ari did a great job answering the why